# How to convert EAR application into one large OSGI bundle and deploy it in Equinox container?

Tags: websphere, osgi, osgi-bundle

As part of cost cutting, management want to cease usage of websphere application servers in developer systems.

I was given task to convert the EAR file to one fat OSGI bundle and deploy it in equinox container. if successful, this set up will be shared among developers and will only be used in developer machines and not in higher enviroments.

I have searched many websites but didn't find any concrete solution.
Kindly share your ideas if any to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An EAR file is simply a JAR file that contains nested JAR files. Those nested JARs form the classpath of the application.

Converting to an OSGi bundle should be as simple as writing a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` for the top-level JAR containing the header `Bundle-ClassPath` header that lists the contained JARs, e.g.:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: a.jar, b.jar, c.jar, ...
```

If the EAR file also directly contains classes that are part of the application classpath, then the new bundle's JAR file should be prepended to the `Bundle-ClassPath` as an entry named '.' (dot), e.g.:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: ., a.jar, b.jar, c.jar, ...
```

Note that the manifest also needs to contain the mandatory OSGi headers, `Bundle-Manifest: 2` and `Bundle-SymbolicName: ...`. There is plenty of information available about this online.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly encourage you look at Open Liberty: https://openliberty.io

Open Liberty is an open source project launched by IBM last year at Java One. The goal of the project is simple: get awesome Java EE technology into the hands of developers.

Open Liberty supports Java EE 7 and MicroProfile as well as other technologies.

Unless you have a strong technical reason to convert the EAR into an OSGi bundle, you can use Open Liberty in your development environment. The install is easy:

`unzip openliberty-18.0.0.1.zip`

Give it a try. I think you'll be pleasantly surprised.

If you have questions, Open Liberty has a very active community and twitter or hit me up on twitter @barecode.

Comment: thanks Michael Thompson. I checked open liberty. how to install features that i need such as admin center, JPA support? there is no installutility file as in liberty server to install needed features.

Comment: Some features in the commercial version are not in the open version (admin center).   You can see what's in it by running wlp/bin/productInfo featureInfo.  Eclipse developer tooling to support using Open Liberty is available as well, more info here: 
https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty-tools

Comment: Thanks Bruce T. That was useful info.